# MariaDB privileges for "SHOW DATABASES" vs "SELECT * FROM information_schema"

Tags: mariadb, permissions, information-schema

I have a user with an access to several databases.

In **MariaDB 10.6.11** I cannot use the following command to list all accessible databases:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
/* SQL Error (1227): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation */
```

On the other hand, I can use this:

```
SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` ORDER BY `SCHEMA_NAME`;
```

On a different server with **MariaDB 10.5.18** "SHOW DATABASES" works fine, even I think users on both servers have the same privileges:

MariaDB 10.6 user (not allowed to SHOW DATABASES):

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dev-all'@'localhost';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dev-all`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `dev-___`.* TO `dev-all`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

MariaDB 10.5 user (allowed to SHOW DATABASES):

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dev-all'@'localhost';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dev-all`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `dev-___`.* TO `dev-all`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Is it caused by different MariaDB versions? Or am I missing something else?

What is the point of not allowing a user to list all of their databases? How can I fix this issue on MariaDB 10.6?

Comment: try granting  the SHOW DATABASES privilege to the user

Comment: That message is poorly phrased.  The name of the one privilege is simply `SHOW DATABASES`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? This allows the user to see all the databases, not only those the user has access to:
GRANT SHOW DATABASES  ON *.* TO 'dev-all'@'localhost';

Comment: [yes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#show-databases)

Comment: @RickJames, but I don't want to allow the user to see *all databases*, only those he/she has access to. And I still don't understand why on one server 'SHOW DATABASES' works and on another does not, even the rights are the same.

Comment: OK, I mis-spoke.  I see nothing relevant in the 10.6 changelogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the following MariaDB option:

> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#skip_show_database
>
> If the server was started with the `--skip-show-database` option, you cannot use this statement at all unless you have the `SHOW DATABASES` privilege.

So it is not related to the version of MariaDB, but to the different configuration on both servers.

It is a strange option, because user is still allowed to use:

```
SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` ORDER BY `SCHEMA_NAME`;
```